# Is "$@" an exception to the double quotes?

Tags: bash

Normally what's inside the double quotes count for one word and so it count for one parameter when calling a program with "...". Is "$@" an exception since it is split in as many words as parameters passed to the shell script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat yes, but also no. It's a different kind of splitting.

`$@` refers to an array; Bash also allows regular variables to be arrays and supports expansions like `${var[*]}` or `${var[@]}`. The latter also expands to *all values* of $var as separate words.

However, if the expansion was inside double quotes, then each individual value *still* behaves as if it was quoted – i.e. word splitting doesn't happen. So there's no exception in *that* regard – `$@` vs `"$@"` is still the same as `$foo` vs `"$foo"`.

#### Demo

```
$ var=("Item 1" "Item 2 has spaces" "Item 3? Item 3.")

$ declare -p var
declare -a var=([0]="Item 1" [1]="Item 2 has spaces" [2]="Item 3? Item 3.")

$ args "${var[*]}"
argc = 2
argv[0] = args
argv[1] = Item 1 Item 2 has spaces Item 3? Item 3.

$ args "${var[@]}"
argc = 4
argv[0] = args
argv[1] = Item 1
argv[2] = Item 2 has spaces
argv[3] = Item 3? Item 3.

$ args ${var[@]}
argc = 11
argv[0] = args
argv[1] = Item
argv[2] = 1
argv[3] = Item
argv[4] = 2
argv[5] = has
...
```

Comment: Oh I did not know that rule for array type variables inside double quote. So if I understood correctly when you type  command "..."  command will not necessarily see 1 parameter (that is argc=2), it depends if the inside of the double quotes contain array-type variables